# Can we block a certain app in enterprise app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on managing the device so I want to block a certain app from running. Can I archive it by using private API without jailbreaking the device? I could not find out any information on that.
Could anyone advise me is there any way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can achieve thorough web API, passing block parameter to registered application. And application have code if app got block parameter then whole app should bypass all functionality.

Comment: Can we apply it to any apps (include apps get from App store)? Could you address how can we pass block parameter to registered application?

Comment: No you can't implement this strategy on any app. You can only for your app custom utility .

Comment: Thanks for your great support, Tirth. Could you provide me some info about blocking apps by web API if possible?